# Проблема с javascript: не работает код, но в консоле ошибок нет - подскажите что я сделал не так

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```html
    <script> 
      var subm = document.getElementById('submit');
      function click(subm){
       if (subm.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') {
       subm.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = '';
       subm.innerText = '';
       subm.value = 'Hide';
       }
       else {
       subm.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none';
       subm.innerText = '';
       subm.value = 'Show';
       };
      }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Show" id="submit" style="width:45px;font-size:10px;margin:0px;padding:0px" onclick="click(subm)"/>
```

Но при этом, такой код работает:

```html
    <input type="button" value="Show" id="submit" style="width:45px;font-size:10px;margin:0px;padding:0px" onclick="
       if (this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') {
       this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = '';
       this.innerText = '';
       this.value = 'Hide';
       }
       else {
       this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none';
       this.innerText = '';
       this.value = 'Show';
       };
    "/>
```

(Тут кусок кода поэтому не работает, но я только новичек, поэтому боюсь что-то испортить , но могу заверить что он рабочий)

Comment: Что значит *не работает код*? Как вы определяете, что он не работает? Как он должен работать?

Comment: Что за вопрос. вы спрашиваете почему не работает код, и в своем же сообщении заверяете что он работает